# Webkit Transition Events

Tags: javascript, events, webkit, css-transitions

Just wondering out loud. Are there any events fired DURING a css3 transition. I know there is webkitTransitionEnd, but is there a webkitTransitionStart or even better (which is what i really need right now) a webkitTransitionDuring (or something similar). I need to set of some functions depending on the position of a div that i move using transition. thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is `webkitAnimationStart`. (Similar enough)

See [Safari Developer Library - WebKitAnimationEvent Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/WebKitAnimationEventClassReference/WebKitAnimationEvent/WebKitAnimationEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009360)

However, there is no such thing as `webkitTransitionStart`.

See [Safari Developer Library - WebKitTransitionEvent Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/WebKitTransitionEventClassReference/WebKitTransitionEvent/WebKitTransitionEvent.html)

Comment: Transitions and animations are fairly distinct things with a different set of properties.